# Restore from backup files recursively in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, restore

I have made a mistake with a shell script and I have backup files that I want to restore.
The code I have to restore my files (which works perfectly) is:

```
for f in *.html~; do mv $f ${f%\~}; done
```

(The backup files end in .html~).

How do I do this recursively through folders?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -type f -name "*.html~" |
while read f; do
    mv "$f" "${f%\~}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use rsync

```
rsync -a /path/to/backup /path/to/restored/folder
```